# Azure Website isn't accessible

Tags: asp.net, azure

I've been hosting my website in azure. The URL is nickgilbert.azurewebsites.net. I can access it just fine once its published...as long as I'm signed into my Microsoft account. For some reason I have to be signed into my account to see my live website and nobody else can see it at all because they get hit with a sign in wall. Is there a setting in Azure that would cause this?

Comment: why don't you post the steps you used to publish? was there a previous "working" version?

Comment: I just right-click the Visual Studio project and hit publish. I know the publish works because I can see my website. I'm on the Dreamspark plan, would that have anything to do with it?

Comment: is the login page of asp.net or microsoft azure itself?

Comment: I think azure itself. I type my user name, get redirected to microsoft sign in page, type my password, hit enter, get taken to my website

Answer (score 0):

If you use ASP.NET MVC:

It seems that you're using authentication in your website. And probably, your default controller/action has the attribute [Authorize]. That's why you see it only after perform a login.

Also:

Take a look at your web.config file. Maybe there's something that redirect your users to that external login page:

for example:

http://i1.asp.net/media/46464/web.config.changessm.png?cdn_id=2015-08-15-002

source: http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/aspnet-and-visual-studio-2012/windows-azure-authentication

Comment: I don't think thats the case, there are no [Authorize] attributes anywhere in my code

Comment: please do not post pictures of code and/or items that people usually select and copy/paste. a better solution would be "In the `<httpRuntime>` tag check the `requestValidationMode` property."